# AJAX com CHTML Image YII Framework

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma requisição AJAX com um Chtml Image. Quando um usuário clicar nessa imagem a requisição é feita através de uma função jQuery, porém estou tendo problemas para pegar o caminho da imagem, minha variável denominada path na função não retorna o caminho, o que há de errado nela?
Segue o código abaixo:

Image:

```
 echo CHtml::Image($string, '', array(
 'id' => 'cimagem', 
 'style' => 'width: 50%;',
 'class' => 'bimagem',
));
```

jQuery:

```
  $('.bimagem').on('click', function(){
     alert('asd');
     var path = $('#cimagem').attr('src').split('\/')[($('#cimagem').attr('src').split('\/')).length - 1]);
     $.ajax({    
                url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('Produtos/SendImage'); ?>',
                data: {caminho: path}
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: 'alert(this)'
            });
    });
```

Comment: Tem um `)` a mais no final de `.length - 1]);`. Tente remover.

Comment: Nossa, nem tinha visto, valeu!!!